# In Cordova is there a way to add platforms declaratively?

Tags: cordova

According to the documentation I've seen, a developer is supposed to run `cordova platform add FOO` before building a project. This seems like a bit of a shortcoming in the management of the build; I'd argue the information about the platforms the project supports should be contained in the project itself.

If I'm bringing on a new developer, she should be able to clone the project repository and build the project without having to ask/guess which platforms are supported. Since the code under the platforms directory is auto-generated, the recommendation is that it not be versioned, but I'm not aware of this information (i.e., the list of supported platforms) existing anywhere else. It seems like this kind of data belongs in config.xml.

Am I missing something, or am I totally off-base here?

Maybe a workaround is to implement a hook that loops through an array of supported platforms and runs `cordova platform add $array_item`, much like the [010_install_plugins.js](http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/) script in the example hooks [referenced by the documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-lib/templates/hooks-README.md#writing-hooks) does. Is the before_build hook a reasonable candidate for this? I'm new to Cordova, so if there are reasons this approach doesn't make sense, I'd be grateful to hear about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, Cordova doesn't support this. But couldn't you get close to what you describe (with a hook) by using a shell script instead?

```
# horrible-javascript-like-shell-script-pseudo-code:
var supportedPlatforms = [ 'ios', 'android', ... ];
for ( platform in supportedPlatforms ) {
  if ( !pathExists ( pathTo ( platform ) ) ) {
    var ret = shellExec ( 'cordova platform add %s', platform );
    # do something with return code if desired...
  }
}
# if all good, proceed with the build
shellExec ( 'cordova build %s', commandLineArguments );
```

Assuming the above was named `build.sh`, you could check the project out (assuming you have the SDKs installed, etc.) and then execute `build.sh` rather than `cordova build...`. If the appropriate `/platforms/<platform>` directory didn't exist, the platform would be added, but if it did, it would simply be skipped. It requires some up-keep to keep the list of supported platforms up to date, and it clutters your project's root directory a bit, but until Cordova supports something like this natively, it might be something to consider.

Comment: It's not as elegant as I wanted it to be, but I guess this is as good as it gets. In any case, like you said, the new developer would have to have the SDKs already installed, etc., so this feature alone wouldn't solve the problem of getting a new dev set up quickly.

On the other hand, much of the environment setup _could_ be done in a shell script, so perhaps it makes sense to abstract `cordova build` with a shell script as well. Not super declarative, but to some extent it depends on how the shell script is structured.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right now (current version is Cordova 3.5) there no way to specify platforms in declarative way.
   This feature actively discussed by the Cordova team and some work done to make this is happens. This is not planned to be implemented earlier then Cordova 4.0 which probably will be shipped in the end of 2014 or beginning of 2015 year.
2. `before_build` hook is not the right place to to, since `cordova build ...` command is checked agains list of already installed platforms before performing build and running hooks.